# Template images are not being loaded, after moving to a differen folder

Tags: 7, distributions

I have moved my complete Open Atrium 2.44 installation from "./Test" to the root folder ("./".)
Everything is being displayed as neatly as it would be but a few default links towards images are still pointing to folders whitin the "./Test" folder.
Is there a setting within Open Atrium 3.44 where i can change the base directory to "./".

As an example: 
Open Atrium points to: example.com/Test/profiles/openatrium/modules/apps/oa_home/images/bg-hero-line.png

While the path of the "bg-hero-line.png" picture actually is:
example.com/profiles/openatrium/modules/apps/oa_home/images/bg-hero-line.png

Thanks in advance :D